# Extracting unique columns from a file into a comma separated list with a particular order

Tags: bash, awk

I have a .csv file with these values

```
product,0 0,no way
brand,0 0 0,detergent
product,0 0 1,sugar
negative,0 0 1, sight
positive, 0 0 1, salt
```

and I want to make a file with comma separated rows in sorted order except  "negative" always is at the end. 
So I want
   ["brand","positive","product","negative"]

I was not able to automate this process so what I did was

1. `awk  -F ',' '{print $1}' file.csv | sort | uniq -c > file2.txt`
2. `awk '{if(NR>1) printf ", ";printf("\"%s\"",$0)} END {print ""}' file2.txt > file3.txt`
   I get "brand","negative","positive","product"
3. Then I manually move "negative" to the end and also append [ and ] to front and back to get

   ```
   ["brand","positive","product","negative"]
   ```

Is there a way to make it more efficient and automate the process?

Comment: I would read them all into arrays "brand","positive","product","negative" and then write them all in order in the way I wanted them

Comment: can you show the `expected output`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

another solution with easy to understand steps

```
$ awk -F, '{print ($1=="negative"?1:0) "\t\"" $1 "\""}' file | # mark negatives
  sort | cut -f2 | uniq |                                      # sort, cut, uniq
  paste -sd, | sed 's/^/[/;s/$/]/'                             # serialize, add brackets


["brand","positive","product","negative"]
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
cut -d, -f1 file.csv | sort -u | sed "/^negative/d" | tr '\n' ',' | sed -e 's/^/["/' -e 's/,/","/g' -e 's/$/negative"]/'
```

Comment: don't get the double quotes using your method.

Comment: Fixed it.  Just added them in the `sed`.  But I'm sure you could have figured that out.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a single `gnu awk` command to make it work:

```
awk -F, '{
   a[$1] = ($1 == "negative" ? "~" : "") $1
}
END {
   n = asort(a)
   printf "["
   for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
      sub(/^~/, "", a[i])
      printf "\"%s\"%s", a[i], (i < n ? ", " : "]\n")
   }
}' file.csv
```

```
["brand", "positive", "product", "negative"]
```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava can we convert this to ["brand", "positive", "product" , "negative"] in the same command?

Answer (score 0):

There are lots of ways to approach this. Do you really want the result as what looks like a JSON array, with square brackets and quotation marks around the column names? If so, then `jq` is probably a good tool to use to generate it. Something like this will do it all as a single `jq` program:

```
jq -csR '[split("\n")|
          map(select(length>0))[]|
          split(",")[0]]|
          sort_by(if .=="negative" then "zzzz" else . end)' file.csv
```

Which outputs this:

```
["brand","positive","product","negative"]
```

If you just want the headings separated by commas in a line without the other punctuation, suitable for heading up a CSV file, you can use more traditional text-manipulation commands:

```
cut -d, -f1 file.csv | 
  sed 's/negative/zzz&/' | 
  sort -u | 
  sed 's/zzz//' |
  paste -d, -s -
```

Or you can slightly modify the `jq` command by adding the `-r` flag and another pipe at the end:

```
jq -csrR '[split("\n")|
           map(select(length>0))[]|
           split(",")[0]]|
           sort_by(if .=="negative" then "zzzz" else . end)|
           join(",")' file.csv
```

Either of which outputs this:

```
brand,positive,product,negative
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl one-liner

```
$ cat unique.txt
product,0 0,no way
brand,0 0 0,detergent
product,0 0 1,sugar
negative,0 0 1, sight
positive, 0 0 1, salt

$ perl -F, -lane ' { $x=$F[0];$x=~s/^(negative)/z\1/g;$rating{$x}++ } END {$q="\x22";$y=join("$q,$q",sort keys %rating) ; $y=~s/${q}z/$q/g; print "[$q$y$q]" }' unique.txt
["brand","positive","product","negative"]

$
```